# How to fix broken LaTeX packages?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, latex

I was trying to install LaTeX using the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` but when 11.5 kb installation was remaining, terminal reported an error that stated:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
libxml-sax-expat-perl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix it? It won't even allow me to remove the LaTeX package.

Comment: Does it suggest to run any code? And have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: yes, it suggests running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. But that turns out to be of no good and ends up returning the same error along with an info that "package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)